# Include Applet in html page

Tags: java, applet

In want to include an applet in my html page, I use an object in my html page to include jar file of my java application, but this jar file never launched, so I'am not able to run the functions defined in my  java application...

This my code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
       <head>
        <link href="../includes/LMSTestContentPackages_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/EmulationCode.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/BrowserDetect.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/About.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="../common/lmsrtefunctions.js"></script>
          <title>Sequencing Test SCO </title>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          //<!-- [CDATA[
             var driver = null;
             var launchTestPassed = true;

             function performTest()
             {
                DetectBrowser();
                if ( ! IE )
                {
                   driver = document.getElementById('NNLMSTestSCODriver');
                }
                else 
                {
                   driver = document.getElementById('LMSTestSCODriver');
               }
                launchTestPassed = driver.testLaunch();
          </script>
       </head>
     <body onload="performTest();">
         <div>
         <!-- LMSTestSCODriver -->
                <!--[if !IE]> Firefox and others will use outer object -->
                <object
                    classid="java:org/adl/testsuite/rte/lms/comm/LMSTestSCOApplet.class"
                    codetype="application/x-java-applet"
                    codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5_0_16-windows-i586.cab"
                    type="application/x-java-applet"
                    archive="LMSTest.jar" height="450" width="450" 
                    name="NNLMSTestSCODriver"
                    id="NNLMSTestSCODriver">

                    <!-- Konqueror browser needs the following param -->
                    <param name="archive" value="./LMSTest.jar" />
                    <param name="code" value="org/adl/testsuite/rte/lms/comm/LMSTestSCOApplet.class" />
                    <param name="MAYSCRIPT" value="true" />
                    <param name="scriptable" value ="true" />
                    <param name="java_codebase" value="../common" />
                    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">

                    <!--<![endif]-->

                    <!-- MSIE (Microsoft Internet Explorer) will use inner object -->
                    <object name="LMSTestSCODriver" id="LMSTestSCODriver"
                        classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
                        codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5_0_16-windows-i586.cab"
                        height="0" width="0">

                        <param name="code" value="org/adl/testsuite/rte/lms/comm/LMSTestSCOApplet.class" />
                        <param name="codebase" value="../common" />
                        <param name="archive" value="LMSTest.jar" />
                        <param name="name" value="SCO" />
                        <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet" />
                        <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">

                        <strong> This browser does not have a Java Plug-in. <br />
                            <a href="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/downloads/index.html">
                                Get the latest Java Plug-in here. </a> </strong>
                    </object>


                    <!--[if !IE]> close outer object -->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
                </div>
            <div id="scoPage">
                <p class="darkBlue_text"> 
                <!-- align="left" removed, need a .css to do formatting-->

                    LMS Test

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    Sequencing Test SCO
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    </p>
                <div id="teststatus">

      </body>
    </html>
```

the function `testLaunch()` is defined in the `LMSTestSCOApplet.class` class. The probleme, is this function(testLaunch()) is never launched. I think that the jar file is never launched, but I don't know where is the error in my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 2) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again. 3) `<body onload="performTest();">` Nope. The 'page loaded' event will fire as soon as the UA has downloaded all the HTML (and possibly the external styles and JS files). It does not mean the applet ..

Comment: .. has loaded and started running.